# tests failing with SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: jestjs

After updating a package "office-ui-fabric-react" from "5.124.0 to "6.128.0", all my tests are failing with following error:

```
 FAIL  src\***.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

\node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\Callout.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './components/Callout/index';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using create-react-app, You probably don't want to eject it.

To solve this without ejecting we need to be able to modify jest configuration without eject.

Luckily there is this library https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

Follow its instruction and install `react-app-rewired` in you CRA project

Then you need to change your `package.json` to include "jest" configuration

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/(.*)$": "office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/$1"
  },
 "transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "node_modules/(?!office-ui-fabric-react)"
 ]
}
```

Resource: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Fabric-6-Release-Notes

---

Update

The latest create-react-app already support `moduleNameMapper` and `transformIgnorePatterns` configuration. 
So there are no need to use `react-app-rewired` anymore.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration

Comment: In my case the changes need to be done in jest.config.js instead of package.json , like https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Fabric-6-Release-Notes documents it.

Comment: This also works for @fluentui-react in case you're having the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

`export` is used in ES modules, whereas because Jest is run in Node it requires common JS modules. See the docs on [transformIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string) on how to convert it to common JS with your TypeScript setup.